# .push_back() on large vector causes std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, heap-memory, bad-alloc

This was compiled on 64 bit VS C++ 2015. std::bad_alloc occurs where x is specifically 1120

```
static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> g_damagefunction;
static std::vector<std::vector<double>> g_has_damagefunction;
static std::vector<double> null_v_double;
static std::vector<bool> null_v_bool;
static std::vector<std::vector<double>> null_vv_double;
int main(){
for (int x = 0; x < 4400; x++) {
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    g_damagefunction.push_back(null_vv_double);
    g_has_damagefunction.push_back(null_v_bool);

    for (int y = 0; y < 2000; y++) {
        g_damagefunction[x].push_back(null_v_double);
        g_has_damagefunction[x].push_back(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
            g_damagefunction[x][y].push_back(0.0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think it is used too much memory. You should be able to see how much memory is used when it reached the crash point.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fafd1d273a5f4e1f)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it ends at 1040. I got expired when I was trying it on coliru.

Comment: I fixed the code a little bit (I was treating a double as a bool). I looked at "No repro" and it seems to only go to 1000-something

Comment: @BryanChen I've also got expired at the 1st run at coliru. No repro though.

Comment: I'm looking at memory management, and, the computer has over 24GB of memory, and the program itself only uses like at the time of crashing 700MB (so it's definitely not a memory limit problem)

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x763C5B68 where x = 1120

Comment: I get `std::bad_alloc` at 4096 when I run the program in a 32-bit chroot. I have no problems when running on a 64-bit system. Are you sure you're running in (and have compiled for) a 64-bit environment?

Comment: I am absolutely 100% sure, Visual Studio is currently configured for 64-bit Release.

Comment: I created a fresh Visual Studio project, and it worked. Had something to do with sharing a directory with another program (I copied an older project's folder and rewrote the program)

Answer (score 2):

bad_alloc here means that you are running out of memory. The size of the double elements in g_damagefunction vector will take (4400 x 2000 x 41 x sizeof(double)) bytes which amounts to about 2.68 GBs of your memory. If you add to it the amount of memory the vectors themselves take up, you can clearly see that either your computer's RAM is insufficient for your program's requirements, or your program is using too much memory. I suspect the latter to be the case.